# Using Chart JS locally in Blazor Hybrid

Tags: chart.js, blazor-hybrid

I try to use Chart JS in Blazor Hybrid.

With the following script it is working fine.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.3.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
```

But I want to use the app off line and need to access ChartJS from the hard drive.
So I downloaded ChartJS from Git and compiled the files locally in order to generate the files in the dist folder.

When I replace the above script by the following:

```
script src="C:\Users\spitzbe\VS_Projects\ChartJS\dist\chart.umd.js"></script
```

I get the following error
[image]

I think that this is related to security features. But is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Does [this Blazor doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#static-assets-limited-to-razor-components) answer your question? That is, move the source file to `wwwroot`  and reference the path relative to that.